# Installing "software centre" on Kali

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux

I'm trying to install some software on Kali 2019.1 (VMware Workstation 12) following instructions [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/23/how-to-install-software-on-kali-linux/),  but nothing is working. I've downloaded the ISO from the official Kali website.

Attempting to install **Ubuntu Software Centre** with `apt-get install software-center` results in

> E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

The **GPK-Application** GUI which is supposedly available from *Applications > System Tools > Add/Remove Software* does not exist. In fact, the **Add/Remove Software** menu item does not exist.

When I open the **Software** application, which in Ubuntu functions like the AppStore, the only thing I get under categories is 'Add-ons'.

What is wrong? It seems I cannot install anything.

Comment: Your guide is from 2013. Information from it is likely outdated. Could you please update your post with the contents of your `sources.list`? I do not think Ubuntu Software center would work well on a non-Ubuntu distro, just a heads up.

Comment: To be honest, you'd almost certainly be better off _not_ using Kali, but instead taking one of the easier-to-use distributions such as Ubuntu, Mint, or even Fedora.

Comment: @kemotep Thanks for the heads-up! The only source is: deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

Comment: @roaima Using Ubuntu *is* easier but I want to get to grips with Kali.